# Appending to the last line of CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv

The code below is what I currently have, however it overwrites any data in the csv file at that time, instead of appending it to the end. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
public void printCustomerList() throws IOException{
        FileWriter pw = new FileWriter("F:\\data.csv");
        Iterator s = customerIterator();
        if (s.hasNext()==false){
            System.out.println("Empty");
        }
        while(s.hasNext()){
            Customer current  = (Customer) s.next();
            System.out.println(current.toString()+"\n");
            pw.append(current.getName());
            pw.append(",");
            pw.append(current.getAddress());
            pw.append("\n");
        }
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027764/how-to-append-data-to-a-file .

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try opening file like this

```
FileWriter pw = new FileWriter("F:\\data.csv",true);
```

Pass `true` argument for appending.

Answer (score 6):

use `FileWriter pw = new FileWriter("F:\\data.csv", true);`

reference: [FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a different constructor for your `FileWriter`:

```
FileWriter pw = new FileWriter("F:\\data.csv", true);
```

For more information see the [JDK API for this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29).