# How to update a file in java?

Tags: java, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to append data to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027764/how-to-append-data-to-a-file)

Quick question here, how can I update an exist file in java? when I open the file like this:

```
 try {
              File inFile = new File("scores.txt");
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(inFile)));
```

all the former content of the file is deleted. but I dont want it to be deleted because I need this information. thanks alot.

Comment: That reads the file, it does not write it. Did you post the wrong code?

Comment: Are you sure these lines are removing the file contents?  Are you also writing to the file at some point in your code?

Comment: If you are writing, could you please update your question with the correct code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(In the absence of the actual code that writes and based on the use of `FileInputStream`)*

Use one of the two argument constructors of `FileOutputStream` who's second argument is a `boolean` indicating if the file should be appended to, rather that overwritten:

```
try
{
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream("scores.txt", true)));
                                         //^^^^ means append
```

Answer (score 2):

The constructurs of a FileOutputStream or a FileWriter can take an additional boolean parameter which indicates whether the written data should be appended to the end of the file (instead of overwriting the file content). Look at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

So you could do: `new FileOutputStream(inFile, true)`, and the result would be that the previous content of the file will remain, and anything you write to the stream will be appended to the end of the file.

If you want to make more advanced updates of the file (e.g. replacing some specific content in the file), there is no specific way in the API to do that, as far as I know. I think you'd have to read from the old file, and write everything you want to keep to a new file and write the replacements to the new file as well. After that you'd remove the old file and rename the new file to the original file name. At least that's the way I would do it, but there might exist better ways that I do not know about.